# Why mail not send from my localhost php 7 in codeigniter

Tags: email, codeigniter-3, php-7

From my localhost,  i cannot send email using gmail account. I've Used php 7.0.9 and codeigniter. I wrote the code in controller is-

```
 $this->load->library('email');
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '25';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'xxx@gmail.com';  
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password'; 
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com');   
    $this->email->to('aaaa@yahoo.com');       
    $this->email->subject("Welcome to xx.");
    $this->email->message('message body.....');
    if ($this->email->send()) {
        $data['success'] = 1;
    } else {
        $data['success'] = 0;
        $data['error'] = $this->email->print_debugger(array('headers'));
}
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
```

But I got the error

```
Array
```

(
    [success] => 0
    [error] => The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from:

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to:

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: DATA

data:

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 12:10:08 +0200

Anyone please give me suggestion about it.

Comment: may be authencitcation problem . your user name password is correct ?

Comment: Yes, My username and password is correct.

Comment: try this $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

Comment: I already tried this.